# I don't know if the data actually got send to the back to process

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

So i'm coding a small basic razor page project, and i'm kinda stuck on this part, i don't know if the CategoryId data actually got send to the back-end for process. I don't really know much about javascript i ask my friends for a javascript code to send some data to the back-end . Here is the code

Note: the page is UserMainPage.cshtml and UserMainPage.cshtml.cs

Sorry if it a bit mess, this code is for the user to sort out the event using their category.

In UserMainPage.cshtml

```
<div style="position: relative; margin-left: auto;">
    <select style="height: 40px; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-radius: 4px; padding-left: 10px; font-size: 16px;" id="categorySelect">
        <option value="" hidden>Category</option>
     @if (Model.TblCategory != null && Model.TblCategory.Any())
    {
    foreach (var category in Model.TblCategory)
    {
        <option value="@category.CategoryId">@category.CategoryName</option>
    }
}
else
{
    <option value="0">No categories found</option>
}


    </select>
</div>
```

Here are the script

```
<script>
    var categorySelect = document.getElementById('categorySelect');
    categorySelect.addEventListener('change', function () {
        var categoryId = parseInt(categorySelect.value); // convert to integer
        window.location.href = "./UserMainPage?categoryId=" + categoryId;
    });
</script>
```

In UserMainPage.cshtml.cs

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int? categoryId, string searchString)
{
    if (categoryId == null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        // If no category is selected and search string is null or empty, return all events
        TblEvent = await _context.TblEvents
            .Include(t => t.Admin)
            .Include(t => t.Category)
            .Include(t => t.Location)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
    else if (categoryId != null)
    {
        // Filter events by category
        TblEvent = await _context.TblEvents
            .Include(t => t.Admin)
            .Include(t => t.Category)
            .Include(t => t.Location)
            .Where(t => t.CategoryId == categoryId)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        // Filter events by search string
        TblEvent = await _context.TblEvents
            .Include(t => t.Admin)
            .Include(t => t.Category)
            .Include(t => t.Location)
            .Where(t => t.EventName.Contains(searchString))
            .ToListAsync();
    }

    return Page();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? It sounds like you are just guessing what is happening. That's always a bad spot to be to understand anything.

Comment: You can try to set breakponit at OnPostAsync to see the value of `categoryId`. Besides, try to use`F12` to see if any error messages in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Using `window.location.href` it's not possible to send a POST request, it does a GET request for the new URL.

You can try the `ajax` to  send some data to the back-end. Besides, the Razor Pages are automatically protected from `XSRF/CSRF`. You should set the `XSRF-TOKEN` when you want to use the ajax to send request in razor page. More details, you could refer to below codes:

1.If you are using the asp.net core6, please add below codes into the program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
```

2.If you are using the asp.net core 5, please add below codes into the startup.cs:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
```

3.Modify the  codes:

```
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var categorySelect = document.getElementById('categorySelect');
        categorySelect.addEventListener('change', function () {
            var categoryId = parseInt(categorySelect.value); // convert to integer  
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./UserMainPage?categoryId=" + categoryId,
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

4.result:

[image]